# Return instance of Service(Class) using Unity

Tags: c#, instance, unity-container

Currently i have class `Factory` which have implemented methods to return instance of Management Service (Some class)

```
public static class Factory
{
    //#region UserNewEditDelete
    public static IUserBM UserCreation()
    {
        return new UserBM();
    }
    //#endregion
}
```

What would be the proper way to rewrite this class `Factory` using Unity Framework?

---

My vision ::

My Factory :

```
public static class Factory
    {
        public static void Register(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            container.RegisterType<IUserBM, UserBM>();
        }
    }
```

Register in Global.asax :

```
Factory.Register(UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer());
```

when i need to use Management Service :

```
UnityConfig.Container.Resolve<IUserBM>()
```

Is it good implementation? Thanks.

Comment: you can delete the whole thing and just inject IUserBM into the things that need it

Comment: So your question is about asp.net mvc and injection inside controllers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creation of unity container :

```
var unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
unityContainer.RegisterType<IUserBM, UserBM>();
```

Usage when you need an instance :

```
var userBm = unityContainer.Resolve<IUserBM>();
```

Unity is smart enough to inject that type when needed, for instance :

```
public class A
{
    private IUserBM userBm;
    public A(IUserBM userBm)
    {
        this.userBm = userBm;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        this.userBm.Work();
    }
}

// this will construct an instance of class A injecting required types
var a = unityContainer.Resolve<A>();
a.DoSomething();
```

---

**Unity with ASP.NET MVC**

After installing the [nuget package Unity.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc/), edit method `RegisterTypes` from `UnityConfig.cs`

```
    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        unityContainer.RegisterType<IUserBM, UserBM>();
    }
```

Now if you need an instance of `IUserBm` in a controller, add a constructor argument :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IUserBm userBm;

    public HomeController(IUserBm userBm)
    {
      this.userBm = userBm;
    }
    ...
```

Unity will create the controller for you providing an instance of the registered type thanks to `UnityDependencyResolver` automatically set up when you install the package.

For more information, see [ASP.NET MVC 4 Dependency Injection](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection)